How to visualize marginal effects with two interaction terms in model?
I am running a regression model with several independent variables and two separate interaction terms, along with country fixed effects and clustering the standard errors at the individual level using the "lm_robust" function from estimatr. Because of the incompatibility of many packages with robust SEs, I extracted the model estimates and the covariance matrix to compute marginal effects by hand, following this tutorial. My issue is that I end up with marginal effects for my two variables of interest both starting at the same place on the y-axis, which seems odd.
The model looks something like this:
mod_sdo_rwa <- lm_robust(Vote ~ gender_f + occ_f + age_f + experience_f + children_f +       ideology_f + origin_f + SDOsummary + gender_f*SDOsummary + RWAsummary + gender_f*SDOsummary, data=FullLaunch_New, weights = weight, fixed_effects = country, clusters = Individ_f, se_type="stata")

Gender is a binary variable and SDOsummary/RWAsummary are both on a continuous scale from 0 to 1.
mod_sdo_rwa <- lm_robust(Vote ~ gender_f + occ_f + age_f + experience_f + children_f +    ideology_f + origin_f + SDOsummary + gender_f*SDOsummary + RWAsummary + gender_f*RWAsummary, data=FullLaunch_New, weights = weight, fixed_effects = country, clusters = Individ_f,   se_type="stata")

beta.hatRWA <- coef(mod_sdo_rwa) 
covRWA <- vcov(mod_sdo_rwa)
z0RWA <- seq(min(FullLaunch_New$RWAsummary, na.rm=TRUE), max(FullLaunch_New$RWAsummary,            na.rm=TRUE), length.out = 1000)
dy.dxRWA <- beta.hatRWA["gender_fFemale"] + beta.hatRWA["gender_fFemale:RWAsummary"]*z0RWA
se.dy.dxRWA <- sqrt(covRWA["gender_fFemale", "gender_fFemale"] +      z0RWA^2*covRWA["gender_fFemale:RWAsummary", "gender_fFemale:RWAsummary"] +    2*z0RWA*covRWA["gender_fFemale", "gender_fFemale:RWAsummary"])
uprRWA <- dy.dxRWA + 1.96*se.dy.dxRWA
lwrRWA <- dy.dxRWA - 1.96*se.dy.dxRWA

beta.hatSDO <- coef(mod_sdo_rwa) 
covSDO <- vcov(mod_sdo_rwa)
z0SDO <- seq(min(FullLaunch_New$SDOsummary, na.rm=TRUE), max(FullLaunch_New$SDOsummary,    na.rm=TRUE), length.out = 1000)
dy.dxSDO <- beta.hatSDO["gender_fFemale"] + beta.hatSDO["gender_fFemale:SDOsummary"]*z0SDO
se.dy.dxSDO <- sqrt(covSDO["gender_fFemale", "gender_fFemale"] +     z0SDO^2*covSDO["gender_fFemale:SDOsummary", "gender_fFemale:SDOsummary"] + 2*z0SDO*covSDO["gender_fFemale", "gender_fFemale:SDOsummary"])
uprSDO <- dy.dxSDO + 1.96*se.dy.dxSDO
lwrSDO <- dy.dxSDO - 1.96*se.dy.dxSDO

Line <- ggplot(data=NULL,aes(x=z0RWA, y=dy.dxRWA)) +
labs(x="Right Wing Authoritarianism/SDO",y="Estimated Coefficient of Gender") +
geom_line(aes(z0RWA, dy.dxRWA, color="red"), size = 1) +
geom_line(aes(z0RWA, lwrRWA, color="red"), size = 1, 
        linetype = 2) +
geom_line(aes(z0RWA, uprRWA, color="red"), size = 1, 
        linetype = 2) +
geom_hline(yintercept=0) + 
geom_line(data=NULL,aes(x=z0SDO, y=dy.dxSDO, color="blue"), size = 1) + 
geom_line(aes(z0SDO, lwrSDO, color="blue"), size = 1, 
        linetype = 2) +
geom_line(aes(z0SDO, uprSDO, color="blue"), size = 1, 
        linetype = 2)

PanelB <- Line + theme(legend.position="right") +
scale_color_discrete(name="", labels = c("SDO", "RWA")) +
ylim(-.04, .1) +
theme_bw() +
theme(axis.title.x=element_text(size=22),           axis.title.y=element_text(size=20),legend.title=element_text(size=20), legend.text=element_text(size=18), legend.position="bottom")

I end up with this graph:

My question is- why do they both start at the same place on the y-axis?
Just to follow up on the package suggestions- another reason why I am struggling is because I would like the visualization to show that marginal effect of gender on the DV (vote) over the range of the two moderators (SDO and RWA). It seems to me like the suggested packages can only give me the marginal effect of SDO or RWA on vote by gender. Am I missing something obvious?

At x = 0, you are calculating dy.dxRWA <- beta.hatRWA["gender_fFemale"] and dy.dxSDO <- beta.hatSDO["gender_fFemale"] (the other terms are zero because x is 0). But those are the same, since both beta.hatRWA and beta.hatSDO are coef(mod_sdo_rwa).

Not an answer to your question, but the marginaleffects package supports robust standard errors and also the lm_robust() function. https://marginaleffects.com/vignettes/plot.html

Also, in your model formula, you have gender_f*SDOsummary twice, but no gender_f*RWAsummary.

Btw, the emmeans is also supported for estimatr model: https://declaredesign.org/r/estimatr/articles/emmeans-examples.html.
